# Applying a method multiple times , a better way to do this?

Tags: javascript

I have displayTabPanel function and im applying it multiples times with different parameters like this :

```
var display = function () {

    displayTabPanel(tab1, tab1_name, tab1_width, tab1_height, tab1_btn);

   displayTabPanel(tab2, tab2_name, tab2_width, tab2_height, tab2_btn);

   displayTabPanel(tab3, tab3_name, tab3_width, tab3_height, tab3_btn);

};

var displayTabPanel = function(tab, tab_name, tab_width, tab_height, tab_btn){
   //...
};
```

i have at least 9 of those calls, and its realy ugly to put it this way ,
is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: i don't understand. Arrays are almost basic constructs in almost every language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its just a readability thing you could do the following:

```
function displayTabPanels(panels) {
    for( i in panels) {
        tab = panels[ i ];

        displayTabPanel(tab.id, tab.name, tab.width, tab.height, tab.class);
    }
}

var panels = [
    {id: 'tab1', name: 'tab1_name', width: 'tab1_width', height: 'tab1_height', class: 'tab1_btn'},
    {id: 'tab1', name: 'tab1_name', width: 'tab1_width', height: 'tab1_height', class: 'tab1_btn'},
    {id: 'tab1', name: 'tab1_name', width: 'tab1_width', height: 'tab1_height', class: 'tab1_btn'},
];

displayTabPanels(panels);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its even cleaner when i used YUI's YAHOO.Dom.batch method  : YAHOO.util.Dom.batch(panels, displayTabPanel); (which   applies displayTabPanel to each element of  panels )

Answer (score 2):

Use an array and a for loop and make a tab object containing those members!

I'm not sure of the specific javascript syntax, but basically rather than tab1, tab2, tab3, etc, you have an array (or list) of tabs, tab names, tab width, tab heights, tab buttons. Then you'd do this:

```
[pseudocode]
for each tab t in array
    displayTabPanel(t.tab, t.name, t.width, t.height, t.button);
[/pseudocode]
```

It's probably better design wise to make a tab object and store tab, name, width, height, and button inside this object, rather than having separate arrays for each. But if you really want separate arrays you can do something like this:

```
[pseudocode]
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    displayTabPanel(tab[i], name[i], width[i], height[i], button[i]);
[/pseudocode]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object (JSON) containing the parameters. Either unnamed like

```
var params = [["tab1", "tab1_name", "tab1_width", ...], [...], ...]
```

Or, better, named like :

```
var params = [{id:"tab1", name:"bla", width:300, ...}, {...}, ...]
```

Then a very simple loop will let you call displayTabPanel with all these params. I left this as an exercise to you but can provide help if you need. BTW, with the second solution, you can pass the object directly to displayTabPanel, which can lead to very rich and elegant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over array of arguments, and call your function for each of them.

```
for (params in [
     [tab1, tab1_name, ... tab1_btn],
     [tab2, tab2_name, ... tab2_btn],
     ...
]) displayTabPanel.apply(params);
```